# Why use "a throb of sensation" when referring to arousal?

Tags: word-choice, historical-fiction, erotica

I found this in *Secrets of a Summer Night* by Lisa Kleypas, set in Victorian England.

> She felt a throb `verb` of sensation `noun`.

Shouldn't "sensation" be an `adjective` instead?

Comment: "of" is usually followed by a noun or noun phrase, whether it's "bottle of wine", "feeling of dread", "sensation of warmth", "shudder of arousal", etc. It would help if you explained the context in which this occurs, what you think it means, and what you think it should be. Try writing the sentence how you think it should be, and see if feels more grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

The verb in your target sentence is felt and not throb.

She is the subject. Felt is the verb. The object is ‘a throb of sensation.’

It borders on a passivity, but falls short of the object experiencing the action. Also, this kind of structure, ‘She felt’ like ‘She thought’ reminds the reader they are reading a story.  That the experiences on the page are being related by a narrator of some one else’s experiences. A more immersive style might be ‘She throbbed.’ Ro ‘She throbbed with desire.’